# transacciones en store mysql

Tags: transacciones

buenos días amigos vuelvo, espero que puedan ayudarme con este caso:
tengo un procedimiento almacenado llamado "sp_salida" el cual dentro de el existe otro procedimiento almacenado llamado "sp_cursorProductoSalida" que ejecuta un cursor, asimismo dentro de este ultimo tengo otro cursor llamado "sp_cursorProductoSalidaKardex"que se ejecuta por casa iteraccion del "sp_cursorProductoSalida" el problema que tengo es que estoy usando transacciones y  al probar mi script veo que la transaccion solo llega a aevaluar hasta el segundo SP, y ya no evalua en el ultimo "sp_cursorProductoSalidaKardex" a pesar que le pongo a proposito algun error las transacciones ya no llegan hasta ahi.

como puedo hacer para que llegue hasta el tercer SP y si tuviera que meter mas SP anidados como seria.

les pongo como esta estructurado el codigo:

```
//SP QUE INICA
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_salida(a,b,c)
MODIFIES SQL DATA
BEGIN
DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION, SQLWARNING
BEGIN
SHOW ERRORS LIMIT 1;
RESIGNAL;
ROLLBACK;
END; 
START TRANSACTION;

//ejecuta codigo insert/update
CALL sp_cursorProductoSalida(a,b); //la transaccion reconoce los errores hasta este nivel

COMMIT;
END


//SP sp_cursorProductoSalida
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_cursorProductoSalida (a,b)
BEGIN

//ejecuta un cursor
INICIA cursor

//este store se ejecuta por cada iteraccion (es otro cursor)
CALL sp_cursorProductoSalidaKardex(a); // la transaccion ya no reconoce el error en este nivel

CLOSE cursor


END
```

espero que se entienda, y puedan ayudarme, no pongo el codigo como es porque es grande, quisiera que me indiquen como se hace en este caso para que las transacciones en mysql reconozca los errores cuando se anidan mas stores.

gracias amigos.

Comment: No entiendo el lío que tienes en el código, Se supone que las SP ya existen ¿no?  ¿Por qué los `CREATE`? ¿Por qué tantos `BEGIN`? Simplemente llama las SP una tras otra con `CALL` **dentro del ámbito de la transacción**, o sea, antes del `COMMIT`. [Mira aquí un ejemplo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20027137/5587982).

Comment: Lo que pasa que el último store hace un cursor sobre cada interacción del anterior, eso es porque tengo que analizar cada uno y hacer ciertas cosas para guardar la información

Comment: Sigo sin entender. Me pregunto si no deberías analizar mejor la lógica que estás siguiendo.